# Can anyone explain why my c++ code for arduino isnt working

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

I coded in C++ so that it takes input from the user and then lights up the corresponding LED
this is my code..

```
int rPin = 13;`
int gPin = 12;
int yPin = 11;
int dTime = 500;
String input;
//Strings
//String red = "red";
String prompt1 = "Enter the color : ";
String conformation = "Entered color is ";
void setup(){
  pinMode(rPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(gPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(yPin,OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  Serial.println(prompt1);
  input = Serial.readString();
  while(Serial.available() == 0) {
    
  }
  if (input == "red"){
    digitalWrite(rPin,HIGH);
    delay(dTime);
    digitalWrite(rPin,LOW);
    delay(dTime);
 } else if (input == "green"){
    digitalWrite(gPin,HIGH);
    delay(dTime);
    digitalWrite(gPin,LOW);
    delay(dTime);
 } else if (input == "yellow"){
    digitalWrite(yPin,HIGH);
    delay(dTime);
    digitalWrite(yPin,LOW);
    delay(dTime);
 } 
//  digitalWrite(gPin,HIGH);
//  digitalWrite(yPin,HIGH);
```

There is no problem with my arduino circuit connection ,I triple checkeed it ...

Comment: Don't you need to call `Serial.readString()` *after* the loop that calls `Serial.available()`? You're calling it before input is available.

Comment: **my c++ code for arduino isnt working** Is not a good problem description. You should describe what you expect in input and what you get.

Comment: What is `String`? If it's a typedef for C-style strings, you must use `strcmp()` to compare them, not `==`. But if it's like C++ `std::string` then `==` is OK.

Comment: You might get more useful help by posting at [arduino.se]

Comment: @Barmar [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) has a [comparison operator](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/string/operators/comparison/) like `std::string`

Comment: @Barmar I changed the Serial.readString() after the while loop but its not working ..

Comment: @S.M.Duly noted :)

Comment: Try printing the value of `input` after you read it.

Comment: @Barmar  I tried to print the input statement but its printing it correctly , And i tried to change all those string statements to int that worked correctly ..

Comment: What do you mean by "changed ... string statements to int"? Example please